# reconfiguring msdos to gpt

Tags: mount, partitioning, parted

Im currently trying to make my sdb gpt and have partitions primary but I don't know how to proceed properly.

what I did was:

1. `sudo umount /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb5`
2. `sudo parted /dev/sdb mklabel gpt`
3. `sudo parted /dev/sdb mkpart primary ext3 0% 30%`
4. `sudo parted /dev/sdb mkpart primary ext4 30% 90%`

and it shows me this:

[image]

How to make type primary and file system like shown in the commands?

Comment: The process is after creating a partition you need to format those partitions as desired. Please follow the provided answer below. But note you need to quit parted first then format them

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen ok and how do you make them primary since it's only the name?

Comment: This is got not MBR, here you can have up to 128 primary partitions. You already have two primary partitions as per your parted command

Comment: Ohhh because I see it's written name not type, so I thought it wasn't primary thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating partitions on the disk in question you need to format the partitions to the desired form using the commands below after first quiting from parted:

```
sudo mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdb1
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb2
```

Comment: Ok it did change the file systems but, how do I make them both primary since it's only the name.

Comment: @PostMaloneM3m3r All partitions in GPT are primary partitions, no need to do anything.

Comment: @mook765 thanks for clearing that up I really thought they weren't primary partitions. I marked this post as the accepted because my partitions are primary and also because all I'll have to do is follow the instructions on this post.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a graphical desktop (for example standard Ubuntu), you can install **`gparted`**

```
sudo apt install gparted
```

and use it in an intuitive way to

- create partition table via the pulldown menu 'Device - Create partition table'
- create partitions and file systems
- modify partitions (move, increase or decrease size, add labels and flags, change content (file system or swap))

Comment: Sadly I don't have a graphical interface :(